# writing a function to draw a decision tree in R

Tags: r

I have written the function:

```
dec.Tree <- function(subject, formula, dfName, treePackage) {
if(treePackage == tree) library(tree)
if(treePackage == tree) churn.tree <- tree(subject ~ formula, dfName)
if(treePackage == tree) plot(churn.tree, main ="Churn Tree using tree package")
if(treePackage == tree) text(churn.tree)
}
```

When I run the function code it creates the function no problem, but when I call the function using the code..

```
dec.Tree(Churn, ., cust.Churn, tree)
```

It returns the error message:

> Error in treePackage == tree  :    comparison (1) is possible only for
>   atomic and list types

Comment: What does 'tree' refers to ? It's not passed as an argument. The error suspects something is wrong with tree. It's isn't a data type which can be compared. Hence, my question.

Comment: @ManishSaraswat tree is the value of the argument treePackage, it is the R package which I want to use to create the tree. However there are also many other packages I need to use which I will also write if statements for.

Comment: You don't need writing these statement. They already are a part of these packages. Try the infamous rpart package.